# How does docker compose work under the hood?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, multiprocessing

How exactly does `docker-compose` work? The documentations only mention running multiple services in parallel, without mentioning *how*. I understand that the images are built and run, but how are they running in parallel?

Does it resemble [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), which runs each of its services in a different OS process? Are all services being wrapped in one container?

How is it handled behind the scenes?

Running `docker-compose up --verbose` only reveals the following, which I am not sure what it means:

```
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Service: web>
```

Comment: if you can read Python, than this mifght be what your after https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/service.py Basicallt its running docker run, with a bunch of pre factored defaulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps clarify things, docker compose is very similar to docker stack (historically they are different, and `stack` is now incorporated into the docker engine itself, but they serve similar roles, and that similarity has increased with time). Fundamentally, it's a Python program. All it's really doing is parsing the YAML file to identify a group of dependencies that need to be met in order to allow containers to be built and started. It fulfills those dependencies and then it starts the containers. It adds functionality to docker by allowing a group of containers and their dependencies to be treated and managed as a single unit, but under the hood it's just API calls.

As far as docker itself, it is tightly integrated with the underlying kernel and uses a concept called "namespaces" that allow for partitioning of kernel level resources (ie. process trees, network, disk mounts, etc...). Each container can be allocated it's own isolated set of kernel resources in which to operate. How this is managed at the host level involves some trickery under `/proc`. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces#Implementation_details):

> The kernel assigns each process a symbolic link per namespace kind in /proc/[pid]/ns/. The inode number pointed to by this symlink is the same for each process in this namespace. This uniquely identifies each namespace by the inode number pointed to by one of its symlinks.
>
> Reading the symlink via readlink returns a string containing the namespace kind name and the inode number of the namespace.

Answer (score 5):

`docker-compose` creates the docker containers for each service. It is similar to manually creating the containers using `docker run` commands for each service mentioned in the docker-compose.yml file.

It also does some extra stuff like creating a network and joining all the containers to the network, optionally building the image from a dockerfile etc.

Comment: I understand that, though my question is specifically how does it run the containers in parallel? Does every service run on a different process?

Comment: Where are you getting "parallel" stuff from? Compose just creates and starts the containers. The containers are no different from how they would run when you manually configure and start them. It's job is not to run containers in "parallel", it is used to start "multiple" containers with a single command.

Comment: I see, then how do containers run in parallel? Say I run `docker run` on two different containers, does each one of them run on a separate OS process?

Comment: I think you are confused about the notion of what is meant by a "container". Container is just a bunch of processes(usually only one) running in their own kernel namespace and thus isolated from other processes on the host machine and processes in other containers. I highly recommend watching this video - [Cgroups, namespaces, and beyond: what are containers made from?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sK5i-N34im8)